# How to drop the "CreateDB" permission for a user?

Tags: postgresql

I did

```
ALTER USER someuser WITH CREATEDB;
```

How could I revoke it please? I tried

```
revoke CREATEDB from crawler;
```

Got error *role "createdb" does not exist*

I am on postgresql 9.6.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just [alter the user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alteruser.html) again and set the opposite option:

```
ALTER USER someuser WITH NOCREATEDB;
```

That should remove the permission to create databases from the user.